# Access module functions in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to access a module function that I have overriden in the class.

```
module Base
    def Hello
        puts "Hello"
    end
end

class Top

  include Base

  def Hello
    puts "hello from top"
  end

  def Hi
    if p == 1
        Hello
    else
        Base::Hello
    end
  end
end
```

But I get the following error -

```
Error:  undefined method `Hello' for Base:Module
```

Is there any way I can access the module function without using self.Hello in function definition.

Comment: you can't access module function without self

Comment: @Veeru Yes, you can.  If the method is defined in the module to be an instance method (i.e. without `self.` preceding it) then inside the class that includes the module it can be accessed as if it were an instance variable, that is, without `self`.  I think what the OP means is that he does not want to *define* the method with `self`.  But then I want to ask the OP, why is it that you don't want to define the method with `self.`?  If you override the method in the class, you'll *have to* refer to it in some special way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You demonstrated the complete misunderstanding of OOP concepts. And, BTW, the method names in Ruby are not to be started with capital letter.

One can not just call an arbitrary method somewhere in the class hierarchy. Whether this was possible, the whole OOP would make absolutely no sense.

One might call the `super` method *from within this method*:

```
module Base
  def hello
    puts "Hello"
  end 
end

class Top 
  include Base

  def initialize p
    @p = p 
  end 
  def hello
    if @p == 1
      puts "hello from top"
    else
      super
    end 
  end 
  def hi
    hello
  end 
end

Top.new(1).hi
#⇒ hello from top
Top.new(2).hi
#⇒ Hello
```

or, one might declare the *module function*, a.k.a. static function and call it from everywhere:

```
module Base
  def self.hello
    puts "Hello"
  end
end

class Top
  # NOT NEEDED include Base
  def hello
    puts "hello from top"
  end

  def hi
    if p == 1
      hello
    else
      Base.hello
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is to make the module's method a module method rather than an instance method.  If you precede the method definition with `module_function`, then *both* a module and an instance method will be created.  This will enable you to access the module method using the module's name (in this case, `BaseModule.hello`).  I've trimmed your question code to the essentials and illustrated how that would work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

module BaseModule

    module_function

    def hello
        puts 'Hello from BaseModule'
    end
end


class MyClass
  include BaseModule

  def hello
    puts 'Hello from MyClass'
  end

  def module_hello
    BaseModule.hello
  end
end

MyClass.new.hello         # Hello from MyClass
MyClass.new.module_hello  # Hello from BaseModule
```

Comment: It's redundant in this case, as is use of `module_function` itself, since in the example, the sole method is used only as a module method (it could have been defined simply as `self.hello`).  As for copying answers, there were no answers posted when I started working on my answer. In addition, you did not include the `module_function` approach creating both instance and module methods. BTW, your tone to both the OP and me is rather harsh.

Comment: “you did not include the `module_function` approach creating both instance and module methods”—`module_function` is just a syntactic sugar for `self.`. My code does not create _instance_ function, it behaves exactly as yours. If you think, the tone is harsh, feel free to flag anything for moderator attention.

Comment: @mudasobwa This is not correct.  I just posted a SO question and answer explaining this, at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37021084/is-defining-a-module-function-with-module-function-the-same-as-defining-it-wit/37021085#37021085.

Comment: I did not understand, what you have tried to explain. I never said `self.foo` creates an instance method, furthermore I said exactly an opposite (you might re-read my previous comment.) Since you never used `BaseModule#hello` as instance function in your example, I made an assumption the goal was to create the module function. That simple.

Comment: You said "My code does not create instance function, it behaves exactly as yours."  My code *does* create an instance function, it creates both. Anyway, I think we understand each other now.  Thank you for your time and effort on SO, I see by your rep that you have done a lot here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are overwriting a instance method of a module within your class, you can call this method using `super`.

```
module Base
  def Hello
    puts "Hello"
  end
end 

class Top
    include Base

   def Hello
     if p == 1
       puts "hello from top"
     else
       super
     end
   end
 end

 t = Top.new
 t.Hello # => "Hello"
```

Comment: Please also describe in words what the code is supposed to do, so the answer is simpler to understand

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't understand meaning of `include`!
When you include a module to  a class methods from a module add  to a object inheritance chain. In this way You can call that methods like own.

```
module A
 def hello
   p 'Hello from A'
 end
end
class MyClass
 include A
end

2.2.2 :010 > mm = MyClass.new
=> #<MyClass:0x00000000ecaa68> 
2.2.2 :011 > mm.hello
"Hello from A"
```

You can use next in your case:

```
module B
 def self.hello
   p 'Hello from B'
 end
end
class MyClass
 def my_hello
  B.hello #direct call from module B
 end
end
```

And one more note: Don't use capitalized name for a method