# Is defining a module function with `module_function` the same as defining it with `self.` in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is defining a module function with `module_function` the same as defining it with `self.` in Ruby?  That is, do they both result in the creation of both instance and module methods?

Answer (score 4):

No.

```
module M1
  def self.foo; end
end

module M2
  module_function
  def goo; end
end

M1.methods(false)           #=> [:foo] 
M1.instance_methods         #=> [] 
M1.private_instance_methods #=> [] 

M2.methods(false)           #=> [:goo] 
M2.instance_methods         #=> [] 
M2.private_instance_methods #=> [:goo]
```

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not the same.  Using `self.` creates only a module method, whereas `module_function` creates both a module and an instance method:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

module M1
  def self.foo
    puts 'foo'
  end
end

module M2
  module_function
  def foo
    puts 'foo'
  end
end


class C1
  include M1

  def test
    puts 'Call M1 as module method:'
    M1.foo
    # puts 'Call M1 as instance method:'
    # foo
  end
end

class C2
  include M2

  def test
    puts 'Call M2 as module method:'
    M2.foo
    puts 'Call M2 as instance method:'
    foo
  end
end

C2.new.test; C1.new.test
```

Results in the following output:

```
Call M2 as module method:
foo
Call M2 as instance method:
foo
Call M1 as module method:
foo
```

If you then uncomment out the 'Call M1 as instance method:' 2 lines, you'll see this error:

```
./m1.rb:24:in `test': undefined local variable or method `foo' for #<C1:0x007feb311767f8> (NameError)
```

This shows that an instance method `foo` was *not* created when the method was defined as `self.foo`.

Comment: Note: `c2.foo #=> NoMethodError: private method 'foo'...; c2.send(:foo) #=> foo`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I don't understand what you're saying, could you explain?  Also, BTW, I fixed my copy/paste error, all were printing out as M1.

Comment: Sorry, I just thought it was worth mentioning that [Module#module_function](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-module_function) makes the instance method private.

Comment: I see, that's interesting.  I've only ever called such methods in the including class so that never occurred to me.  Thanks!

Comment: I see in my comment I forgot `c2=C2.new`. No wonder it was puzzling.